# Printing PDF books

Tags: printing

I've been taking up reading some of [Sonatype's Maven books](http://www.sonatype.com/documentation/books), available online, but I find it more relaxing to read on paper rather than on screen.

Still, loose A4 sheets do not bring me close enough to a *book reading experience*. Aside from ordering a print copy, what can I do to print/bind a PDF to be as close as possible to an actual book?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do one of three things, depending on the book:

- Print to 2-sided A4 and bind in a lever-arch for storage or dedicated (thinner) binder; this works really well for technical books where I can read a single chapter in a small binder, but page chapters back and forth into my lever-arch collection as required
- Print to 2-sided A5 and bind in a dedicated A5 folder (or 6-hole punch for my A5 organiser which comes everywhere with me). Same benefits as above, although you need A5 paper and a printer that handles it
- Print to [pocketmod](http://www.pocketmod.com/) format (I use a pstops script in linux). This is brilliant for keeping wallet-sized chapters handy at all times; useful for when you find yourself waiting in a line with time to read but no book.

Also (can you tell I'm an avid reader?) I have a Sony Reader that's always got things on it. Not so good for technical books (PDFs with images/figures/tables are a nightmare), but great for novels. But that's a bit beyond the scope of your question :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use an imposition software to impose it as a booklet before printing. You will then be able to print two book pages on one A4 side and with duplexing, 4 book pages on one A4 sheet. Try looking for the words, "free imposition booklet" in Google. At some point I found a print driver addon for Mac OS X which did it on the fly.

Comment: Problem is when there's alot of pages and you fold them together, they wouldn't align.

Answer (score 3):

I've used a comb binder (see [comb binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_binding) on Wikipedia), with good results.  Check at an office supply store.  You get your book, with thicker covers, and a spine that's only moderately annoying.  It does lay pretty flat, which is an advantage over regular books.

Comment: Got one at work. Not my favorite binding by a long way, but they work. Use a stiff cardboard for bindings to get a more booklike feel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried this way, but the printouts are considerably thicker when compared to the book. How do you solve that?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't solved that.  It's a second-best solution.

Answer (score 2):

check out lulu.com  I have used them for several one-copy print jobs and found their services and products to be very reasonable.
If i remember correctly they were about 1/5 the price of kinkos.

Answer (score 1):

I usually print 2-sided, with 2 or 4 pages per side depending on the text size and length of material I am printing (like a chapter). I have been fortunate to always be in the vicinity of a printer that also handles stapling or binding, so this process is automatic as well.

Answer (score 1):

i'm sure many of you will find this post right-in-the-bull's-eye.

http://forums.adobe.com/thread/316484?tstart=0

rgrds, 
alex

Answer (score 1):

I googled for glue book binding to find a post I'd read years ago about just painting glue onto a stack of printed pages, and instead found many useful-looking DIY approaches.  In particular there was a terrific one on a blog named Talk Like a Duck.  He uses an inexpensive purchased program to create properly organized, 4 pages to a sheet, booklets that are then assembled into the book. Very well done presentation.

Comment: I assume that this the blog post : http://talklikeaduck.denhaven2.com/2009/09/12/and-now-for-something-completely-different-diy-bookbinding-on-the-cheap . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your local print shop may be able to do [VeloBinding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VeloBind). I've found it to be satisfactory for the type of use you're describing.