# How to make a pdf booklet using imposition in OSX?

Tags: pdf

How do I make a booklet from a pdf, using a mac with Snow Leopard? Ideally I would like to be able to split my document into multiple booklets (say 10 - 20 pages in each) so that when I bind them they can lie reasonably flat.

I've noticed there is a 'booklet' option when printing from Preview, but it the options are greyed out when I choose it.

I saw this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/42722/printing-pdf-books) previously, but some of the software mentioned is now obsolete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found one source to do this:

http://web.mac.com/vogelbusch/Site/Programs/Eintr%C3%A4ge/2009/7/22_Create_Booklet_1.1_support_Snow_Leopard.html

Comment: dead link reported

Answer (score 2):

The best software for this purpose I have found is [Cheap Impostor](http://www.cheapimpostor.com/).

It has the features you describe:

> - Imposes PDF files for books and    magazines
> - Reorders and 2-ups pages for binding    magazines and books
> - Sheets per signature can be varied    from 1 to magazine/booklet
> - Supports automatic and manual duplex    printers, with and without collation

It is already useful in the unregistered version, but registration at $35 is reasonable and worth the cost.

The website has some useful links how to actually bind the book. I have used this process and added some improvements for my own needs.

I have printed and bound many books and booklets, usually by printing out 1-page signatures, folding them and glueing them with wood glue. I use a homemade press similar to those described in the links, but made from metal. I cut a piece of gauze bandage or book muslin and put it over the still wet glue. This makes the binding more durable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cloud-based impostor option: http://impostor.herokuapp.com/

It worked when I tried it.

Comment: dead link reported